# Tupling of indexed constraints in haskell

Tags: haskell, constraints

Is it possible to do a pointwise tupling of indexed constraints in Haskell ?

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds        #-}


import Data.Kind


class Paramed t where
   type Cxt0 t :: Constraint
   type Cxt2 t :: (* -> *) -> Constraint

data And a b

instance (Paramed a, Paramed b) => Paramed (And a b) where
   type Cxt0 (And a b) = (Cxt0 a, Cxt0 b) -- OK
   --type Cxt2 (And a b) = (\@m -> ((Cxt2 a m, Cxt2 b m))) -- does not work
   type Cxt2 (And a b) m = (Cxt2 a m, Cxt2 b m) -- does not work either
```

It leads to the following

```
error:
    • Number of parameters must match family declaration; expected 1
    • In the type instance declaration for ‘Cxt2’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Paramed (And a b)’
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: oops, added the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use a named class, i.e., something like

```
instance (Paramed a, Paramed b) => Paramed (And a b) where
   type Cxt0 (And a b) = (Cxt0 a, Cxt0 b) -- OK
   type Cxt2 (And a b) = C a b

class (Cxt2 a m, Cxt2 b m) => C a b (m :: * -> *) where
instance (Cxt2 a m, Cxt2 b m) => C a b m where
```

turning on undecidable instances. (You can use another name than `C`, of course)

In Haskell, the kind `* -> *` is not inhabited by lambdas like `\ t -> [t]`, since there are no type level lambdas. We need to declare a named type (using `data` or `newtype`) and use that to inhabit `* -> *`.

The kind `* -> Constraint` is similar: you need a named class.
Ditto for `(* -> *) -> Constraint` or any other `... -> Constraint` kind.

If I remember correctly, using a named type / class is needed to make type inference possible.

Comment: Wait, but if defining such constraint as `Ctx2 (And a b) m = ...` is legal, then why doesn't the OP's original attempt work?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Ah, right, thank you! I forgot to eta-contract. Should be fixed now. The whole point is to avoid mentioning the `m`, on both sides.

Comment: Ah, I had tried a variant of the first version on my own, but could not make it work for the same reason :)) Thank you for the excellent perspective and comment on kinds